# GKE metadata server pod issues with new nodes during autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, workload-identity

We have an issue with gke workload identity.We enabled workload identity for our prod clusters.when enable workload identity it creates daemon set.whenever you application required service account key to access the gcp resource this make a api call to metadata server for accessing service accounts

Issue:-
In morning we have some nodes autoscaling so when a new node came then first our application pods got scheduled and then only these daemon set pods got scheduled.These time then application pods got restarted because in our application will try to access an api call to metadata server pods for initiating some beans for bigquery client

I read some docs also they are suggesting some priority class.
But this gke daemon set pods already have a priority class but it won't work in this usecase